# Dynamic Query to Print out the resultset from a table

Tags: sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I want to print out the dynamic query result so that i can use as a script for some tasks.This is the scenario where i got stuck, i am not able to print out the result as it return only the last value because of OUTPUT param limitation
Is there any way to print all the 3 INSERT statement.

```
    --IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL


    CREATE TABLE #temp (Command varchar(8000))
    INSERT INTO #temp 
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO Test1(column1,column2)values(1,2)'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO Test2(column1,column2)values(1,2)'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO Test3(column1,column2)values(1,2)'

    DECLARE @Column_string varchar(max)
    DECLARE @Column_string_Out varchar(max)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @Column_string = Command FROM #temp'

    --PRINT(@SQL)
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,N'@Column_string varchar(max) OUTPUT',@Column_string = @Column_string_Out Output
    --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
    PRINT(@Column_string_Out)
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Command varchar(8000))
INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Test1(column1,column2)values(1,2)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Test2(column1,column2)values(1,2)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Test3(column1,column2)values(1,2)'

DECLARE @Column_string varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'Declare  cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Command FROM #temp'
exec sp_executesql @SQL

open cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @Column_string

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Print @Column_string

FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @Column_string

END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur    
DROP TABLE #temp
```

**OutPut:**

```
(3 row(s) affected)
INSERT INTO Test1(column1,column2)values(1,2)
INSERT INTO Test2(column1,column2)values(1,2)
INSERT INTO Test3(column1,column2)values(1,2)
```